# Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx] though spring-tx-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar is in classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions, apache-spark

I am trying to initialize spring context in Spark action (foreach) using below code while doing that I am getting following error. I am getting this initialization error only while initialize in spark action otherwise its working fine.

```
stage 0.0 (TID 4, 10.129.146.216): org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: URL [file:/beans.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
```

Code details:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(file:///beans.xml);
```

beans.xml (I have added spring-tx-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar in classpath even)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="package" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: can you show your `pom.xml`?